# FileSystemAccessRule получить права на папку

Tags: c#, acl

Есть метод который для заданной папки возвращает права пользователей. Не совсем понятно как вытащить эти самые права оттуда. В отладчике я вижу все свойство, однако когда я присваиваю его переменной, то там только одно "право", и то самое первое. Делал `ToString()` - тоже самое. Как получить этот массив *? Однако `Console.WriteLine` без проблем выводит эту инфу.

```
void FindInheritedFrom(FileSystemAccessRule rule, string path)
            {
                var security = File.GetAccessControl(path);
                var accessRules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

                var matching = accessRules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.AccessControlType == rule.AccessControlType && r.FileSystemRights == rule.FileSystemRights && r.IdentityReference == rule.IdentityReference);

                if (matching != null)
                {
                    if (matching.IsInherited) FindInheritedFrom(rule, Directory.GetParent(path).FullName);
                    else { 
                    dic.Add(rule.IdentityReference.ToString(), rule.FileSystemRights.ToString().Split('|').ToList());
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мужики, никогда так не делайте!
Как раз разбираюсь в этом вопросе и ни как не мог понять, почему FileSystemRights не возвращает коллекцию ... ?
По внимательнее почитал в заголовке https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=netframework-4.7.1
Биты! Тут биты! Так что тут 1 значение!

```
Console.WriteLine((int)accessRul.FileSystemRights);
```

Вернёт число в десятичной системе, переводим в двоичную, открываем вышеуказанную ссылку с документацией и "понеслись волосы назад" от перевода битиков в права ...

К примеру:

```
Это в двоичной системе - 1180095
Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                100100000000110111111

ReadAndExecute  000100000000010101001
Write           000000000000100010110
Synchronize     100000000000000000000
```

Comment: Преобразовывать в int не надо, побитовые операции и с перечислениями прекрасно работают.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
 dic.Add(rule.IdentityReference.ToString(), rule.FileSystemRights.ToString().Split(',').ToList());
```

PS: rule.FileSystemRights.ToString() возвращает строчку прав разделённую запятыми, а не '|'.